# How can I change the color of the marker on the dash that indicates an application is "up"?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, accessibility

Is is possible to change the dot on the Dash (or Dock) icon to yellow or green so I can see it?

I am very colour blind. In particular, I simply can barely detect red light. There is a small dot (I finally realised) on the Dash that indicates that an application has a window open or that the application is running. I just need to be able to see it without spending ten or fifteen seconds trying different angles and staring to determine whether an application is already running.

Ubuntu 18.04; up-to-date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in normal GNOME environment

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-color
```

will give the present color

Example:

```
maduri@i7-4770U:~$ gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-color
'#0000FF'
maduri@i7-4770U:~
```

to set the required color..

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-color "#0000FF"
```

for yellow or green color your can replace "#0000FF" with "yellow" or "green".

Alternatively you can use the GUI tool `dconf-editor` like below

[image: changing the color of "running-dot"]

Note: *dconf-editor* isn't present by default. You can install it from the Software Center.

---

You can also make the dot bigger:

For example, to do so run

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep running-dot
```

You'll get output like this:

```
dkb@dkb:~$ gsettings list-recursively | grep running-dot
ca.desrt.dconf-editor.Settings saved-view '/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/custom-theme-running-dots-border-width'
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-customize-running-dots true
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-border-color '#e95420'
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-border-width 2
org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-color '#e95420'
dkb@dkb:~$
```

Then, open *dconf-editor* as in the image below and make the desired change:

[image: Changing the sise of "running-dot"]

Comment: You could also add a way to make the dots bigger: `org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock custom-theme-running-dots-border-width 6` for example. I found that, after reading your answer, with `gsettings list-recursively | grep running-dot`.

Comment: Hi this is nice.. Plz edit the answer.. Thank Y0u..

Answer (score 5):

A much simpler way would be to install the [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/) extension and change the marker's color, size and style using the settings it offers.

You can change the Dash to Dock extension settings via Tweaks. If you don't have Tweaks installed, you can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

After running Tweaks, go to *Extensions* on the left-side bar and click the cog icon next to the Dash to Dock extension. Navigate to the *Appearance* tab and you will find the *Customize windows counter indicators* option, as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: dash to dock settings]

You can select the marker's style using the drop-down menu next to this option (I use *Segmented*).

To change the marker's color and size, click the cog icon, turn on the *Customize indicator style* knob and set your preferred marker color and border width. As you can see in the next screenshot, I have chosen a green marker with zero border width (for the purpose of demonstration).

[image: customize running indicators]