# Gnome dock on the bottom of the screen cannot be moved and it hides the window bar

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ubuntu-dock, dock

I upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.03 LTS, and all went well. However, after the restart, the dock in Gnome 42.9 was now instead of the left screen side on the bottom, blocking the windows bar.

[image]

I remembered that I moved it to the left using system settings. However, `Settings` does not have `Dock` or `Appearance` options, as seen on websites.

[image]

`Tweaks` has an `Appearance` section but nothing to change the dock.

[image]

I also installed `gnome-extensions` but this allows only to turn the dock on or off, nothing else.

[image]

What am I missing here? I remember that it was rather easy to change the dock location in 20.04.

**Update**
Trying to reinstall the desktop with `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop` did not change anything.
I went also through [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359102/missing-dock-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-sudo-apt-upgrade-and-restart) to no effect.
Maybe related, maybe unrelated - the font in the popup to indicate the name of the program is now after the upgrade white on white, rendering it unreadable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1148194/757139) suggesting to use `dconf-editor`. Under `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/dock-position`, one can define the dock position:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing the desktop. It won't remove you programs. Open a new terminal (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`) and type `sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. Hit enter, wait until it finishes and reboot.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion but this has not changed anything.